# Box2D mousejoint rotation

Tags: qt, box2d, qml

I would like to implement a zero gravity world where objects in the world can be drag/dropped around with the mouse.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import Box2D 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 1000
    height: 500
    id: global
    property bool dragged: false
    property variant joint: null
    property variant body: null

    Component {
        id: jointComponent
        MouseJoint {
            world: world
            bodyA: anchor
            dampingRatio: 0.8
            target: Qt.point(350.0,200.0);
            maxForce: 100

        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        onPressed: {
            global.createJoint(mouse.x,mouse.y);
        }
        onReleased: {
            global.destroyJoint();
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            if(global.dragged == true)
            {
                global.joint.target = Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y);
            }
        }
        anchors.fill: parent


    }

    function createJoint(x,y) {
        if(global.joint != null) destroyJoint();
        var body = global.body;
        if(body == null) return;
        var mouseJoint = jointComponent.createObject(world);
        mouseJoint.target = Qt.point(x,y);
        mouseJoint.bodyB = body;
        mouseJoint.maxForce = body.getMass() * 30.0;
        global.dragged = true;
        global.joint = mouseJoint;
    }

    function destroyJoint() {
        if(global.dragged == false) return;
        if(global.joint != null) {
            global.dragged = false;
            global.joint.destroy();
            global.joint = null;
            global.body = null;
        }
    }

    World {
        id: world
        anchors.fill: parent
        gravity: Qt.point(0,0)

        Body {
            id: anchor
            x:300
            y: 300
            width: 10
            height: 10
        }
            Body {
                id: forrepeat
                x: (40 + Math.random() * 720)
                y: (40 + Math.random() * 520)
                width: 100
                height: 50
                bodyType: Body.Dynamic
                //rotation: Math.random() * 360
                fixtures: Polygon {
                    density: .5
                    friction: 0
                    restitution: 0.5
                    vertices: [
                        Qt.point(0, 0),
                        Qt.point(0, 50),
                        Qt.point(100, 50),
                        Qt.point(100, 0)
                    ]
                    categories: Polygon.Category10
                    collidesWith: Box.Category1 | Box.Category2 | Box.Category3 | Box.Category4

                }

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
                    border.color:Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
                    smooth: true

                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    propagateComposedEvents: true
                    onPressed: {
                        global.body = parent
                        mouse.accepted = false
                    }
                }
            }




    }
}
```

World has it's gravity set to 0 in X and Y. However, when I pick up any of the bodies, they are fine on the mouse click, but as soon as I move, the  objects rotate around wheerver i clicked the mouse within the object .If I let go of the mouse, they start to spin out of control.

Ideally, I would like only a little movement on my objects that I am moving with the mouse. If it is a rectangle, say, then orient the object so that the right side edge of the rectangle faces in the direction the mouse is moving.

Comment: I am using this version of Box2D qml port: https://github.com/folibis/qml-box2d

Comment: May be you want `fixedRotation: true` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Btw, you can grab source from main repo at https://github.com/qml-box2d/qml-box2d